# Horizontally-scalable, immediate-consistency graph-database?

Tags: graph-databases

Is there any horizontally-scalable, immediate-consistency graph-database?

Comment: Isn't a "immediate consistency" and "horizontal scalability" a fundamentally conflicting goals (due to CAP theorem)? However, I'm interested in such database, too :)

Comment: @wizzard0 Now I understand what you meant at the time. I was so stupid.

Comment: Wow, thanks for following up! You were fine :) every expert at anything was once a beginner. Today, I'd add "if you dissect what exactly `consistency` and `scalability` means for your use case(s), you will often find a solution, even when it's impossible in general". For a contrived example, if you have millions of readers, and only one writer -- there's absolutely no problem with CAP. There's a lot of papers on arXiv in recent years exploring various definitions of consistency/scalability, because every app is now distributed.

Comment: @wizzard0 That's interesting. CAP is about general cases. I think such optimizations on CAP always need concrete cases to get specialized into which I don't have now. Thanks again anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is eight years old and that the graph database market has essentially come into existence during this period but there are now possibly multiple answers.

One such answer is Objectivity/DB. It is an object-oriented database with built-in graph capabilities including node/edge semantics, navigational queries, and an object/graph query language called "DO".

Objectivity/D uses fully ACID-compliant transactions in all interactions with the database and it can scale a database across multiple files/disks on the same machine or across multiple files/disks on multiple machines. Specifically, the nodes of a single connected graph can be distributed across multiple machines.